# primitive #primSocketSendDone: in Socket failed

Tags: mongodb, smalltalk, pharo

I am using Mongotalk and Pharo to run a bunch of analyses.

For every analysis I run a new Pharo instance with the same image and it all works fine until, at a random point, I get a PrimitiveFailed as follows:

```
^[[31mPrimitiveFailed: primitive #primSocketSendDone: in Socket failed
^[[0mSocket(Object)>>primitiveFailed:
Socket(Object)>>primitiveFailed
Socket>>primSocketSendDone:
Socket>>waitForSendDoneFor:
Socket>>sendSomeData:startIndex:count:for:
Socket>>sendSomeData:startIndex:count:
Socket>>sendData:count:
SocketStream>>flush in Block: [ socket sendData: outBuffer count: outNextToWrite...etc...
BlockClosure>>on:do:
SocketStream>>flush
LittleEndianStream>>flush
InsertOperation(MongoOperation)>>flush
InsertOperation(MongoOperation)>>write
Mongo>>insert:collection:
MongoDatabase>>insert:collection:
MongoCollection>>insert:
MongoCollection>>add:
MyClass>>methodThatCallsAddOnMongoCollection
```

and after that all my analyses fail even though I run a new Pharo process for each one.

Anyone got any ideas what is wrong here and why?

cheers,

Comment: How many analyses are you talking about, and are you running them all in parallel?

Comment: And on which platform?

Comment: If you're on a *nix system you might want to check the maximum number of open files with `ulimit -n` and the number of currently open files (e.g. `lsof | wc -l`).

Comment: Running on Linux, sequentially so I doubt it's too many open files or connections, but I will look in to it

Comment: Are you starting them from a shell script? Then you should check your mongodb connection settings

Comment: MongodDB settings are good, data shows up in collections before the primitive starts failing.

Comment: That's not the settings I mean. The Mongo settings, not the smalltalk ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by modifying my client code to store more data less frequently (i.e. cache more in memory) and the problem went away, now i can even run 16 Pharo instances in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience in this follow up

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a 1024 socket limit somewhere [somewhere](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/vm-dev/2014-October/016633.html). The vm list probably is the best place to ask

Comment: Should be up again soonish. There are some problems with the box running the mailing lists. You can try http://forum.world.st/Squeak-socket-problem-help-td4783827.html